# Using TextboxList events and callbacks

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, callback, jquery-callback, textboxlist

Has anyone gotten callbacks working with Guillermo Rauch's [TextboxList Autocomplete](http://devthought.com/projects/mootools/textboxlist/)? I've tried multiple ways to bind and multiple events (e.g. *hover*) - nothing seems to register.

```
$('#entSearch').textboxlist({unique: true, plugins: {
            autocomplete: {
                minLength: 3,
                queryRemote: true, 
                placeholder: false, 
                remote: {
                    url: "{{=URL(r=request, f='call/json/suggest')}}", 
                    extraParams: {type: "", guid: ""}
                    }
                }
            }, 
            onHover: function(token) {
                alert('hover 1');
            }
        });

        $('#entSearch').hover(function() {
            alert('hover 2');
        });

        $('#entSearch').bind('hover', function() {
            alert('hover 3');
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author enabled listeners in a very specific way for TextboxList (see "Events" on [this page](http://devthought.com/projects/jquery/textboxlist)):

```
var t = new $.TextboxList('#entSearch', {unique: true, plugins: {
            autocomplete: {
                minLength: 3,
                queryRemote: true, 
                placeholder: false, 
                remote: {
                    url: "{{=URL(r=request, f='call/json/suggest')}}", 
                    extraParams: {type: "", guid: ""}
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        t.addEvent('bitBoxAdd', function(bit) {
            alert('add');
        });
```